# Как реализовать копирование файлов с одинаковыми именами?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как реализовать копирование файлов с одинаковыми именами под разными именами, а не перезаписывать созданный файл при нахождении одноимённого файла?

```
#КОД ИЩЕТ ФАЙЛ И КОПИРУЕТ ЕГО В УКАЗАННОЕ МЕСТО#
import os

name = 'pic one.jpg'
disk = ('C:\\')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(disk):

    if name in dirs or name in files:
    print(f'We find {name} in {root}')

    filen1 = (f'{root}' + str('\\') + f'{name}')
    filen2 = 'C:\\Users\\vcras\\Desktop\\test\\pic.jpg'

    file1 = open(filen1, 'rb')
    file2 = open(filen2, 'wb')

    file2.write(file1.read())

    file1.close()
    file2.close()
    print('COPY COMPLETED')

print ('THE END')

input()
```

Comment: вопрос в чем, собственно?

Comment: **Непонятна суть вопроса**
В этот вопрос следует включить больше подробностей и уточнить проблему.

Comment: Прошу прощения, ошибочно отправил без корректировок. Сейчас вопрос скорректирован.

Comment: вы берёте фотографию name и сохраняете на рабочий стол. если там есть такая фотография name то её нужно переименовать name2, а взятую сохранить name ?  так должен работать код ?

Comment: @Интик На диске имеется неизвестное кол-во файлов с одинаковым названием "pic one". Нужно найти их все и сделать копии, но уже с разными последовательными названиями (пример: pic1, pik2, pic3.......) чтобы избежать перезаписи одного и того же файла найденным с  аналогичным названием.

Comment: @strawdog На диске имеется неизвестное кол-во файлов с одинаковым названием "pic one". Нужно найти их все и сделать копии, но уже с разными последовательными названиями (пример: pic1, pik2, pic3.......) чтобы избежать перезаписи одного и того же файла найденным с аналогичным названием.

Comment: @Kromster На диске имеется неизвестное кол-во файлов с одинаковым названием "pic one". Нужно найти их все и сделать копии, но уже с разными последовательными названиями (пример: pic1, pik2, pic3.......) чтобы избежать перезаписи одного и того же файла найденным с аналогичным названием.

Comment: Вы можете редактировать свой вопрос - добавьте описание туда

Comment: @strawdog отредактировал вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону модуля `shutil`.

Пример ниже проверяет существует ли уже файл с таким же именем, что и оригинал. Если да, добавляет к его имени уникальное число. Для примера, это общее число файлов до копирования нового `len(listdir(outpath))`.

```
from os import path, walk, listdir
from shutil import copy2

name = 'pic1.gif'
source = r'C:\\'
outpath = r'C:\\result'

for root, dirs, files in walk(source):
    if name in files:
        print(f'We find {name} in {root}')

        originalpath = path.join(root, name)
        copypath = path.join(outpath, name)

        if path.isfile(copypath):
            new_name = str(len(listdir(outpath))) + name 
            copypath = path.join(outpath, new_name)

        copy2(originalpath, copypath)

        print('COPY COMPLETED')

print ('THE END')
```